Stop future internet-archived SE network pages from self-navigating to the live version of the snapshot page
When I save a snapshot of a network page on web.archive.org, the snapshot navigates to the live page. Like this. This also happens for snapshots saved before I started noticing this issue (like this).
@balpha explained in the tavern that this is due to some (very old) JS to guard against SE sites being framed to prevent clickjacking, and that JS was added instead of more "current" methods because those methods didn't exist / weren't well-supported at the time that was implemented.
web.archive.org gets the HTML just fine, but attempting to view that archive snapshot resource as a webpage with JS enabled will always redirect to the live/source page. It seems to be a recent issue (due to changes on web.archive.org's end that now trips up on SE's JS?) archive.is is unaffected.
While this cannot be fixed for previous crawls, please fix it for future crawls by removing this script as the more modern browsers SE officially supports support the more "current" methods in question.

Just to clarify, that is not at all what I said. Quite the contrary. I said that we made no changes at all to cause this, and I definitely didn't mention the "unauthorized access" stuff. This code has existed for 15 years -- my assumption is that something changed with how the Internet Archive includes archived JS.

Looking at the JavaScript the Wayback machine serves it shadows window, self and various other variables but for top it has a commented line declaring that variable. This causes the top !== self check that Stack Overflow does in their JavaScript to return true and then change the current location. I guess they recently commented that line of code.

Yep, it looks like they're injecting a bunch of proxy objects through a library called "wombat" that leave the JS global object in an inconsistent state.

If its on the WBM's side, and not here - what'd be the 'right' workflow to fix it? Would SE be willing to get in touch with IA about this bug, or would it be left to the community?

@balpha sorry for putting words in your mouth. I clearly wasn't reading properly, and ended up fabricating a cause from my poor understanding of a collection of recent events. I'm quite embarrassed. that's not the kind of person I want to be. please forgive me for that.

@starball It's all good, it was a misunderstanding. Unfortunately there's not much we can do -- even if we changed something now, it wouldn't help with anything that's already been archived. This needs to be fixed on their end.

Not-great workaround: if you add id_ after the timestamp in a way back URL, you get the original version without any transformation: https://web.archive.org/web/20241108062326id_/https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball?tab=topactivity This breaks of the JavaScript and images because the paths are wrong, but you can at least see the content of the page without being redirected away.

IMO “remove the extremely obsolete redirection JavaScript” is an actionable and reasonable request, and this should remain tagged as “feature-request” or something like that. Even if it doesn’t apply retroactively, that code isn’t providing any value any more, so it should probably be cleaned up anyway, and as an added bonus this conflict goes away moving forward.

@balpha Per Jeremy's comment above, this can at least be fixed for future crawls by removing the script and replacing it with a more modern method.

@Sonic I don't even disagree that that code is probably unnecessary these days, but please stop suggesting that this is somehow broken because it's "non-modern" code. This code is just fine and does exactly what it's supposed to do. This is broken on the Internet Archive. Has anyone pinged them yet?

@balpha I was going off of the question body which uses the phrase "more 'current' methods". Since the SE policy is to only code for modern browsers which do support said methods, I think the best thing to do is to remove it so future crawls will work while we wait for the Internet Archive to fix it for previous crawls. Also, I think it's better if someone from within SE contacts them since they can explain the code and its intention better.

The Internet Archive, and their overworked under-resourced staff, are still recovering from a catastrophic cyber attack so I’m not inclined to nag them to spend time in this now. However, this Wombat library appears to be open source and maintained by someone else, so perhaps one of us could see if we can identify a fix and they’ll pick it up in their next dependency bump. Putting the responsibility on IA seems unfortunate: they need to maintain compatibility with 99999999 web sites. Stack Overflow needs to maintain compatibility with ~1 archiving service, and the fix is trivial.

Having taken a quick look at wombat.js: It would probably be possible to work-around, although it'll be a bit hacky. However, the Internet Archive is still using a version of the library from last year, so an upstream fix might not be picked up quickly. The specific line that's causing this behaviour in the version it's using was changed in a more recent version, but I think the new version would still cause the same issue.

Someone should probably file an issue suggesting they consider implementing a hacky workaround to un-break Stack Overflow's old archives. It might be possible to get away with updating wrapScriptTextJsProxy to also insert a check for window == top, and alias their wrappers to the same object instead of creating distinct objects in that case. The code will probably be a bit inelegant but it should be possible. (I'm not currently on a machine where I have access to my GitHub account, so I can't do this now. Maybe later if time allows.)
